# Calling stored procedure with an IN and OUT Parameter from Spring Batch

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, java-stored-procedures

I am attempting to execute a stored procedure from Spring Batch, the stored procedure has two parameters, an IN parameter and OUT parameter. What I want is to get the result set and the out parameter when the stored procedure is called.

I referred to [StoredProcedureItemReader](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/item/database/StoredProcedureItemReader.html) and [StoredProcedureItemReaderBuilder](http://%20https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/item/database/builder/StoredProcedureItemReaderBuilder.html)

I can use this to call a stored procedure that has only IN parameter, however, I can't call after registering OUT parameter.

If we refer raw JDBC template we could use, it is possible to call a Store Procedure with IN and OUT variables using https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html

And I believe that `StoredProcedureItemReader` or `StoredProcedureIteamReaderBuilder` uses `CallableStatement` behind the scenes.

My question is, how do I register OUT parameters to execute within Spring Batch using [StoredProcedureItemReaderBuilder](http://%20https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/item/database/builder/StoredProcedureItemReaderBuilder.html)

Here's a sample code I tried

```
@StepScope
    @Bean
    public StoredProcedureItemReader<MyRow> rowReader(@Value("#{stepExecutionContext[tableName]}") String tableName) {
        return new StoredProcedureItemReaderBuilder<MyRow>()
                .procedureName("GetNameCountByFname")
                .parameters(
                        new SqlParameter[]{
                                new SqlParameter("fname", Types.VARCHAR),
                                new SqlOutParameter("total", Types.INTEGER)
                        }).
                        preparedStatementSetter(
                                new PreparedStatementSetter() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps)
                                            throws SQLException {
                                        ps.setString(1, "bob");
                                    }
                                }
                .rowMapper(new MyRowMapper(tableName))
                .name(tableName + "_read")
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .build();
    }
```

The following error is given:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at java.util.ArrayList.elementData(ArrayList.java:422) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:435) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.CallableStatement$CallableStatementParamInfo.getParameter(CallableStatement.java:283) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.CallableStatement.checkIsOutputParam(CallableStatement.java:634) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.CallableStatement.getObject(CallableStatement.java:1356) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
```

The following stored procedure is called

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE GetNameCountByFname(
    IN  fname VARCHAR(25),
    OUT total INT
)
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    INTO total
    FROM `first`
    WHERE `name` = fname;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Hello Saad, welcome to SO , have you tried to drill down where are you getting the arrayIndex out of bound exception

Comment: @AshishShetkar Thanks for the welcome.Yes, I did. A parameter index, which I don't have any control of, was being set causing it to be -1. Mahmoud's answer tells that I isn't possible with this approach. Therefore, now I am think to implement an ItemReader where I will explicitly call the SP using plain old JDBC calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is, how do I register OUT parameters to execute within Spring Batch using StoredProcedureItemReaderBuilder

That's not possible. This feature has been already requested but was rejected. Please find more details in https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/2024.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In such cases, should I alternatively implement an ItemReader that explicitly reads from a stored procedure with In and Out variables?