# Calling a stored procedure with IN and OUT parameters using custom ItemReader

Tags: java, spring-boot, stored-procedures, jdbc, spring-batch

I asked this question on Stackoverflow on calling a stored procedure with IN and OUT parameters using `StoredProcedureItemReader`, but unfortunately, the answer was that such support isn't available, and I have to implement my own ItemReader.

[Calling stored procedure with an IN and OUT Parameter from Spring Batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62187086/calling-storedprocedure-with-an-in-and-out-parameter-from-spring-batch/62192225?noredirect=1#comment110007727_62192225)

So, I went ahead and wrote this sample code. I am able to call my stored procedure, however, it's being called infinite times whenever the read() method is called in a Batch step.

```
@Component
public class MyStoredProcItemReader implements ItemReader<MyRow> {
    @Autowired DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    public MyRow read() throws Exception, UnexpectedInputException, ParseException, NonTransientResourceException {
        try (
                Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection();
                CallableStatement statement = conn.prepareCall("{call GetNameCountByFname(?, ?)}");
        ) {

            statement.setString(1, "bob");
            statement.registerOutParameter(2, Types.INTEGER);

            boolean hadResults = statement.execute();

            Integer totalBook = (Integer) statement.getObject(2, Integer.class);

            System.out.println("Total: " + totalBook);
            Map<String, Object> results = new HashMap<>();

//            ResultSet resultSet = statement.getResultSet();
//            ResultSetMetaData metaData = resultSet.getMetaData();

//            int col = 1;
//            while (resultSet.next())
//            {
//                String columnName = metaData.getColumnName(col);
//                Object value = resultSet.getObject(col);
//                results.put(columnName, value);
//                ++col;
//            }
//
//            int columnCount = metaData.getColumnCount();
//            for (int col = 1; col <= columnCount; col++) {
//                String columnName = metaData.getColumnName(col);
//                Object value = resultSet.getObject(col);
//
//                results.put(columnName, value);
//            }

            while (hadResults) {
                ResultSet resultSet = statement.getResultSet();

                // process result set
                while (resultSet.next()) {
                    String title = resultSet.getString("id");
                    String description = resultSet.getString("name");
                    int rating = resultSet.getInt("LastSynchronizationVersion");

                    System.out.println(
                            "| " + title + " | " + description + " | " + rating + " |");
                }

                hadResults = statement.getMoreResults();
            }

            statement.close();

            MyRow row = new MyRow();
            row.tableName = "tableName";
            row.row = results;
            return row;
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

What did I do wrong, and what's the right approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am able to call my stored procedure, however, it's being called infinite times whenever the read() method is called in a Batch step.

An [`ItemReader`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/ItemReader.html) is expected to return `null` at some point to signal the end of the data set. This is how the driving chunk-oriented step knows that there is no more data to read and gives the control to the enclosing job to move to the next step (if any).

So in your case, you need to make sure your item reader returns `null` at some point.